# Play Youtube video from link

Tags: android, video, youtube, youtube-api

I'd like to play video in VideoView in Android. I've searched internet and I'm not sure and I'm lost with this topic. I'd like to simply be able to play any youtube videos and actually can not nothing. I've read that I need special library YoutubeAndroidPlayerApi. Ok I've got it in my project on eclipse. Then I need special API KEY and also generated it for Android. And now I really don't know how to make it working. Anyone could help me to do this. It should only play video. No login in and search some other things (playlist etc) are not coded in my application.

I've got simple view:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TEKST TESTOWANIE"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/displayMovie"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
         />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is over because I don't know what is the next step. Please help me.

Comment: Try using webview and load the url of and embedded youtube video.

Comment: Take a look at this https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/